# Hover on unusal nav bar (ONLY CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want to make a navigation bar. I supposed a big block would be shown when i hover a the nav bar. However, it didn't work.

This is my html code.

```
<div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="header">
        <a id="logo" href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        <div id="nav">
            <div class="selectors"><a href="#">aaa</a></div>
            <div class="selectors"><a href="#">bbb</a></div>
            <div class="selectors"><a href="#">ccc</a></div>
            <div class="selectors"><a href="#">ddd</a></div>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <div id="innerContainer">
        <div class="navHidden"></div>
        <div class="navHidden"></div>
        <div class="navHidden"></div>
        <div class="navHidden"></div>

        <div id="content"></div>
        
    </div>
```

And, this is my css.

```
#nav{
position:relative;
float:left;
width:600px;
padding-left:30px;
padding-top:25px;
}

.selectors{
width:150px;
position:relative;
float:left;
margin:0;
z-index:10px;
}

.selectors:hover{border-bottom-color:silver;background-color:silver;}

.navHidden{
width:760px;
height:100px;
background-color:silver;
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
display:none;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

I want the web become as follow:

> |.selectors |.selectors | .selectors | .selectors |
>
> |     navHidden .....(only shown when hover)......|

I can only allowed to use html and css, because this is homework.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by big block?

Comment: You cannot do that as long as your innerContainer is placed outside the .selectors. I assume you also want to show different sub navs for different .selectors. So you could place a .innerContainer into each .selectors element and than use something like that in your css: `.selectors:hover .innerContainer { display: block; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was adapted so now your have desired layout. But it is **NOT PERFECT** I did not remove excess rules. Do your homework by yourself

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
        <a id="logo" href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        <div id="nav">
            <div class="selectors">
                <a href="#">aaa</a>
                <div class="navHidden">Lorem ipsum text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="selectors">
                <a href="#">bbb</a>
                <div class="navHidden">Lorem ipsum text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="selectors">
                <a href="#">ccc</a>
                <div class="navHidden">Lorem ipsum text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="selectors">
                <a href="#">ddd</a>
                <div class="navHidden">Lorem ipsum text</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-top:25px;
}

.selectors{
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    z-index:10px;
}

.selectors:hover{
    border-bottom-color:silver;
    background-color:silver;
}
.navHidden{
    width:760px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:silver;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.selectors:hover .navHidden {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to create your navigation.

```
  <style>
  ul, li {list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; float: left;}
  li a{display: block; width: 100px; height: 40px;}
  li a:hover{display: block; width: 100px; height: 40px; background: red;}
  li ul {display: none;}
  li:hover ul {display: block;}
  </style>
  </head>
   <ul id="nav">
       <li class="selectors"><a href="#">aaa</a></li>
       <li class="selectors"><a href="#">bbbb</a>
            <ul id="innerContainer">
                <li class="navHidden">222</li>
                </li>
            </ul>
       </li>
  </ul>
```